# Zip, name and move files to another director using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have an incoming data feed that I want to write a bash script to process on a scheduled basis. Part of the script will need to get new files and archive them like described below:

1. Find all files/subfolders in data.
2. Zip those files/subfolders, and name the zip by current date.
3. Move the zip to archive
4. Delete the files/subfolders in data

Thinking something like this...

```
#!/bin/bash
        
client=name
data=/path/to/$client/data
archive=/path/to/archive/$client
        
if [ -z "$(ls -A $data)" ]; then
        echo "No data to archive"
elif [ -n "$data" ]; then
        echo "Archiving data"
        find $data -print | zip -j "$(date +"%m-%d-%Y@%T")".zip -@
        mv "$(date +"%m-%d-%Y@%T")".zip $archive
        rm -vrf "${data:?}/"*
        echo "Archive complete"
 else
    echo "Archive failure. The Slayer rejects your code."
fi
```

Am I getting close?

Comment: Why would you want to find all files and subdirectories in a directory to zip? Why not zip the entire directory?

Comment: The directory is an FTP drop location, and I really only need to zip and move the directory's contents on a daily basis. I'm no expert though so open to suggestions!

Comment: I've updated the original code. Goal is to zip contents of data, mv to archive, empty data. Any flaws or issues with how I've set this up?

Comment: ``Am I getting close?`` It's been over a week and you probably have done by now.

Answer (score 0):

No, your code does not work because find "$data" -print will print $data which is a list of files. Also, it will overwrite all zip because all have the same name (e.g. 2021-01-22.zip)

You have multiple options, if you want to zip entire folder and move this zip to another directory:

```
zip -r $(date +"%d-%m-%Y").zip /path/to/directory-1/
mv $(date +"%d-%m-%Y").zip /path/to/directory-2
```

If you want to zip each file by separate:

```
#!/bin/bash

data=$(find /path/to/directory-1)
archive=/path/to/directory-2

if [ -z "$data" ]; then
    echo "No data to archive"
elif [ -n "$data" ]
    then
    echo "Archiving data"
    for i in $data; do
    f=${i//\//_}
    zip "$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")_$f.zip" $i
    mv $(date +"%d-%m-%Y")_$f.zip $archive
    done
    echo "Archive complete"
else
    echo "Error"
fi
```

I have been replaced the /path/of/file by path_of_file because if not you can not create a file with "/" characters.

Whatever, I suggest you use rsync or similar in order to only backup the new files of the directory.